# How to increase availability of EKS

Tags: amazon-eks

As EKS SLA, a 99.9% avialbility is committed by Amazon.
How I can increase that to 99.99% (or even 99.999%)?  Would it help if I add master/slave nodes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to do this and still call your setup an AWS EKS Cluster. It is defined in the EKS SLA that an EKS Cluster means that the control plane would be run by AWS. Three masters in different AZs provide pretty much good HA.

A workaround may be introducing a queue between the control plane (i.e. the k8s api) and your requests. The queue can retain the requests which were not successful due to availability issues and can again send the request based on some priority or time-based logic. This won't increase the HA for real-time tasks, but wouldn't let requests made from asynchronous use cases go to waste.